# Lazy="true", seems to have no effect, everything is loaded

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm stuck with several properties in a mapping (many-to-one, many-to-many, one-to-many) where I everywhere defined `lazy="true"` (for many-to-one: `lazy="proxy"`). Here an example within the mapped class `HelperPerson`:

```
    <set name="WorkingTimes" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="true">              
        <key column="PersonId"/>
        <one-to-many class="Proj.Model.WorkingTime, Proj"/>
    </set>
```

It doesn't help anything. NHibernate fires for each row of the connected `WorkingTimes` a query (by the way, it wont change anything if I use `lazy="false" fetch="join"`) right after I call the `.List`-function (before touching any property which should trigger the query):

```
    NHibernate.IQuery hibQuery = _HibSession.CreateQuery("SELECT hp FROM Proj.Model.HelperPerson hp WHERE hp.Person.PersonId = 19 ");
    hibQuery.List(resList);
```

Do I forget something obvious? Or could there be something like a hidden, global configuration which tells NHibernate to ignore lazy-loading in general?

Thx for any tipps!
sl3dg3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there was some logic going on within the setter, which triggered NHibernate to load everything. Setter and logic = evil... :-/